# How to bet having an $x> 1/2$ probability of winning

Tags: probability, game-theory, gambling

In a certain game, I have an $x> 1/2$ probability of winning. I have $y$ dollars at the start. I want to know what percentage $z$ of $y$ I should bet so that $y$ grows as much as possible with the number $n$ of games played.

Comment: Do you mean, *how should you manage your bankroll?* Search “bankroll management”on twoplustwo poker forums

Comment: Suggest you look up the Kelly criterion

Comment: For safety - bet minimum.  For fastest growth - bet maximum.